# in php, how do i truncate a string by x characters starting from the end?

Tags: php, string, truncate

How do I truncate a string thats 120 characters to 100 characters but have the count of the length start from the end of the string? So that the 20 characters are removed from the beginning of the string rather than the end?

Answer (score 2):

`$newString = substr($oldString, -100)`
will return the last 100 characters of a string (or `false` if the string is shorter).

Answer (score 1):

Use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) i.e.

```
$newline = substr($oldline, 20);
```

or

```
$newline = substr($oldline, -100);
```

Comment: +1. I find it amusing that when someone has answered a question to the point then why do others keep posting same answer again and again. This answer answers the question, yet there are now 5 more same answers!

Comment: He specifically asked for a count from the end of the string (potentially to handle strings of lengths other than 120 characters exactly) which this answer doesn't quite handle.

Comment: It does. If you look at the PHP Manual. This answer exactly works like what was asked, this will take 20 characters away from the start of the string, like was asked by OP. Here it is again `So that the 20 characters are removed from the beginning of the string rather than the end?`

Comment: @winterblood - I thought the user is capable of looking it up to achieve way of getting the desired result.

Comment: and `but have the count of the length start from the end of the string`

Comment: Mmm ok then maybe  the question itself was confusing. +1 for your answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function

```
$str = "Hello How are you?"
$str2 = substr($str, 5); // "How are you?"
```

For first 20 characters

```
$string = substr($str,20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `substr` in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
substr("abcdef", 20); // "abc.." is of course an example string. 
                      // this sets it to position start of 20 from left.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$shortString = substr($string, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest to start from the end. If you know already that is going to be 100 chars:

```
   $string=substr($yourstring,-100);
```