# How to remove last 2 digit of number in php?

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, digit

I have some numbers in a PHP array similar to

```
$num = array(+0100,-0200, +0000);
```

I want to remove the last two digits (00). Can anyone help?

Comment: share your exact code

Comment: there is no number 0000 it's only 0 , and the same for others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in php, how do i truncate a string by x characters starting from the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674534/in-php-how-do-i-truncate-a-string-by-x-characters-starting-from-the-end)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$num = array("+0100","-0200", "+0000");
foreach($num as $key=>$val)
{
  $num[$key] = substr($val, 0, -2);
}
print_r($num);
```

Demo https://eval.in/839153

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to for or foreach.

```
$arr =  array("+0100","-0200", "+0000");

$arr = array_map( function($val) { return substr($val, 0, -2); }, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "+01"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "-02"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "+00"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/FgWuP

Answer (score -1):

```
 foreach($num as $key=>$value){   
         $num[$key]= substr($value,0,strlen($value)-2);
     }

    foreach($num as $key=>$value){   
        $num[$key]= $value;
        echo 'the'.$key.'value ='.$num[$key] ;
     }
```

> The substr() function returns a part of a string.
>
> Note: If the start parameter is a negative number and length is less than or equal to start, length becomes 0.
>
> syntax substr(string,start,length)
>   Good Luck

Good luck!

Comment: This answer is not best practice.  `strlen()` is an unnecessary call.  Two foreach loops is sloppy/unnecessary.  See Andreas' or Satish's answers for proper execution.